# JFace Wizard: How to have the Progress Bar not disabling the Wizard GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, progress-bar, jface, wizard

I have a Wizard and I need to run a Job in background. 
I would like that a Progress Bar shows the fact that job is running, but, at the same time, I don't want that the GUI components of the wizard become disabled.
In other words, I would like to continue to use the wizard while the progress bar is showing the Job in background.
Is it possible?

Thanks to everyone will help me!

Answer (score 1):

You can, you just need to make sure you start a new Job to do the background work, but UI updates still happen in the UI thread:

```
    Job job = new Job("name") {
        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            // Do some work

            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Update UI
                }});
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };
    job.schedule();
```